# Magento 2: Using Cart Based Rules to apply Free Shipping only to specific products

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-shipping

Hello StackExchange Magento People!

We are trying to apply Free Shipping only to specific products - products that have an attribute like "Free Shipping" = 'Yes'.

Our configuration is set such that we only have two shipping methods:
Free - which should only appear to designated products
and
Flat Rate - which should apply to the rest of the products.

We've setup the Cart Rules to apply Free Shipping with a straightforward rule of "If attribute = Free Shipping = Yes" give free shipping.

Yet, what is happening is that regular products are given the free shipping treatment when added to the cart.

Any insight or tips would be great on resolving this issue.

Thanks!

Rad

Comment: You can select Specific Country wise right where you want to apply Free Shipping

Comment: You mean rule created but not working ?

Comment: Refer this http://www.emagentosupport.com/2018/12/magento-2-cart-rule-free-shipping-for.html. i have tried and got success.

Answer (score 3):

You can set rules as

**In Condition**

You can use assign rule for each sku

[image]

**In Action**

select Free Shipping  For matching items only

Comment: Hi @Priyank I want to apply free shipping for the particular category products.